# Python reverse list with k steps, in-place operator vs standard operator

Tags: python, list

**Python list `nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, k = 3. rotate the array to the right by k steps.**

What's the difference between **A:**

```
nums[:k] = nums[len(nums)-k:]
nums[k:] = nums[:len(nums)-k]
```

and **B:**

```
nums[:k], nums[k:] = nums[len(nums)-k:], nums[:len(nums)-k]
```

The output for A is `[5,6,7,5,6,7,4]`
The output for B is `[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]`

Can you please explain how it worked and why the output is different?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
By the time you post, we expect that you have simulated the code by hand (since it's quite short), and have inserted strategic `print` statements to trace the values.  Show the results of this work, and explain where you don't understand compound assignment and/or slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to check how `nums` looks like after every operation (with `print(nums)` in scratch or calling it (`nums`) in terminal). Next time, try it yourself.

In **A**:
With the first line (`nums[:k] = nums[len(nums)-k:]`): `nums = [5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7]` - you've substituted `nums[0:3]` (`1, 2, 3`) with `nums[4:7]` (`5, 6, 7`).

Then, with the second line (`nums[k:] = nums[:len(nums)-k]`): `nums = [5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 4]` - you've substituted `nums[3:7]` (`4, 5, 6, 7`) with `nums[0:4]` (`5, 6, 7, 4`).

In **B**:
You've done this operations "in place", without changing the `nums` between them. You've "grabbed" `1, 2, 3, 4` and `5, 6, 7`, made list `[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]` and assigned it to `nums` overwriting its value (`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, You made it very clear to me! Agreed, I will print it out after every operation to try.

Comment: Hello, Can you please explain why the second solution is in place? Is it because they are all written in one line?

Comment: I' don't know if it's good term but generally yes. It happens like I've written above - you firstly grab the `nums[len(nums)-k:]` and `nums[:len(nums)-k]` from `nums` but it's still not changed. And then, you assign this respectively by `=` to `nums[:k]` and `nums[k:]` what's just changing `nums`.